# Work of a flying tennis ball

Tags: calculus

We are taught that work $$W=\int_a^b F(x) dx,$$ $F$ is force and $x$ is distance.

The question says that a 2 oz. tennis ball is served (by Andy Roddick, I think) at $153 \frac{mi}{hr}$. Find the work required.

There is no distance. Is there enough information here?

Comment: $\frac 1 2 mv^2 = W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do work on the ball to give it kinetic energy.
$$W = \frac 1 2mv^2 \implies W = 23409\frac{\textrm{oz}\cdot\textrm{mi}^2}{\textrm{h}r^2} $$in Fred Flintstone units.

Comment: Where $m$ is in kilograms and $v$ is in meters per second... unless you want to end up with some really weird units for $W$...

Comment: @Barry What?${}$

Comment: @Barry I'm giving it in the same units he used: Fred Flinstone units.

Comment: I'm using the same units as the text. Ounces is a unit of weight, not mass. And where's the integral? This is from a Calculus 2 textbook.

Comment: I don't get something: Is ounce a unit of force or mass?

Comment: @Jeff I treat it like a unit of mass.

Comment: @Jeff You could [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ounce) it. It's a unit of **mass**.